# Symfony4 Uncaught BadRequestHttpException on Docker

Tags: php, symfony, docker, symfony4

I create a proxy api to make a bridge between soap and rest in symfony4. In order to properly catch my soap exception I created the Listner below. Localy my soap exception are catched and thrown as `BadRequestHttpException`. When I deploy my code on a Docker container I have the following error: `Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\BadRequestHttpException:`

There is my listner:

```
class TrinityListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => array('onKernelException', -64),
        );
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if (($e = $event->getException()) instanceof \SoapFault) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your issue has nothing to do with Docker.

You created a **TrinityListener** which is listening to **kernel.exception** event (a [GetResponseForExceptionEvent](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/GetResponseForExceptionEvent.php) object actually). When this event occurs the **onKernelException** method is executed and it is unusual to throw an exception here without catching it properly. Your initial exception is an instance of [\SoapFault](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapfault.php), so you throw a **BadRequestHttpException**, that's fine but the exception is not caught. That's the the issue, the error is very explicit, you should use a **try...catch** to fix this.

[Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) from php documentation:

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler().

So you can fix your issue like this:

```
class TrinityListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => array('onKernelException', -64),
        );
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        try {
            if (($e = $event->getException()) instanceof \SoapFault) {
                throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
            }
        } catch (BadRequestHttpException $e) {
            $response = new Response();
            $message = sprintf(
                'Error %s with code: %s',
                $exception->getMessage(),
                $exception->getCode()
            );
            $response->setContent($message);
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello than you for your answer it works, I put a lighter way to do it below. One question remains why when I throw an exception I get a 500 http code in prod and 400 in dev.

Comment: No more information? Just 500 Internal server error? Did you check the logs? (apache or nginx error logs)

Comment: I have following in prod and val:
[2018-12-18 13:39:47] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception: Could not connect to host {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\BadRequestHttpException(code: 0): Could not connect to host at /home/clem/PhpstormProjects/TrinitycoreConsole/src/EventListener/TrinityListener.php:49)"} []

Comment: I think I have found why is due to the debuger which catch the exception thrown in the Listner. The Debuger give the good HttpResponse instead of the symfony kernel in prod no debug -> no good response. You can see the behaviour by following`Debug::enable()` in index.php.
Finaly I fix it with your solution. I was jus curious to understend why.
Have a nice day !

Comment: Yes in dev environment there is an Exception Handler used to permit you display Exception info for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0):

The following way is lighter to do the same thing:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    if ($event->getException() instanceof \SoapFault) {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        $response->setContent($event->getException()->getMessage());
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```